# How to properly join TOP 1 fields to SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

How can I properly join the fields I have in the comment block to the SQL query?  I have a billing phone number on the order header, but on the order lines, there is a shipping phone number for each line.  The billing and shipping can be different.

On every order line of one order, it's 99% the same shipping number, but I want to do `Top 1` and not `group by` just incase some data gets messed up.

I think `UNION` might get me what I want, but it seems like there is a better way to get everything in one query and not copying & pasting the same "where" clauses.

```
SELECT a.Order_no
       ,a.Customer_no
       ,a.BILL_LAST_NAME
       ,a.BILL_FIRST_NAME
       ,b.email
       ,a.BILL_ADDRESS1
       ,a.BILL_ADDRESS2
       ,a.BILL_CITY
       ,a.BILL_STATE
       ,a.BILL_POSTAL_CODE
       ,a.BILL_COUNTRY
       ,b.Address_Type
       ,a.BILL_PHONE
       ,a.BILL_PHONE_EXT
       ,a.Order_Date
       ,a.billing_status
       ,a.PO_Number
       ,a.Customer_comments
       ,a.ShipMethodShipperDesc
       ,a.ShipRate
       ,a.CouponDiscountCode
       ,a.CouponDiscount
       ,a.CustomerDiscount
       ,a.CustomerDiscountPercent
       ,a.SalesTaxTotal
       ,a.Payment_Method
       ,a.Credit_Card_Type
       ,a.Credit_Card_Number
       ,a.Order_Date
       ,a.BILL_TYPE
       ,a.Order_Net
       /* I added these lines but would like them joined properly */
       /*-------->*/
       , (select top 1 SHIP_ADDRESS1 from LineItems C where c.ORDER_NO = a.ORDER_NO)
       , (select top 1 SHIP_ADDRESS2  from LineItems C where c.ORDER_NO = a.ORDER_NO)
       , (select top 1 SHIP_CITY from LineItems C where c.ORDER_NO = a.ORDER_NO)
       , (select top 1 SHIP_STATE from LineItems C where c.ORDER_NO = a.ORDER_NO)
       , (select top 1 SHIP_POSTAL_CODE from LineItems C where c.ORDER_NO = a.ORDER_NO)
       , (select top 1 SHIP_COUNTRY from LineItems C where c.ORDER_NO = a.ORDER_NO)
       /*<-----------*/
FROM Orders AS a
       ,Customers AS b
WHERE a.customer_no = b.customer_no
       AND a.AccountName = 'mywebaccount'
       AND a.billing_status <> 'Canceled'
       AND a.transferred = 0
       AND a.order_status <> 'Canceled'
       AND EXISTS (
              SELECT *
              FROM LineItems c
              WHERE c.order_no = a.order_no
              )
ORDER BY a.order_date
       ,a.order_no
```

Comment: you can join with a subquery where you can put that top. btw long time I don't see a implict join

Comment: How can I join multiple fields with a subquery?

Comment: you are joining only ORDER_NO and retrieving multiple columns. But yes you can use any boolean predicate in a join

Comment: I changed the last part of the query to this and it doesn't work. I think I'm close though: `FROM Orders a
INNER JOIN Customers b on b.CUSTOMER_NO = a.CUSTOMER_NO
INNER JOIN (select top 1 ORDER_NO, SHIP_ADDRESS1, SHIP_ADDRESS2, SHIP_CITY, SHIP_STATE, SHIP_POSTAL_CODE, SHIP_COUNTRY from LineItems) c on c.ORDER_NO = a.ORDER_NO`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest something like:

```
SELECT Order_no
       ,Customer_no
       ,BILL_LAST_NAME
       ,BILL_FIRST_NAME
       ... 
       ,SHIP_ADDRESS1
       ,SHIP_ADDRESS2
       ,SHIP_CITY
       ,SHIP_STATE
       ,SHIP_POSTAL_CODE
       ,SHIP_COUNTRY
FROM (

SELECT a.Order_no
       ,a.Customer_no
       ,a.BILL_LAST_NAME
       ,a.BILL_FIRST_NAME
       ,b.email
       ,a.BILL_ADDRESS1
       ,a.BILL_ADDRESS2
       ,a.BILL_CITY
       ,a.BILL_STATE
       ,a.BILL_POSTAL_CODE
       ,a.BILL_COUNTRY
       ,b.Address_Type
       ,a.BILL_PHONE
       ,a.BILL_PHONE_EXT
       ,a.Order_Date
       ,a.billing_status
       ,a.PO_Number
       ,a.Customer_comments
       ,a.ShipMethodShipperDesc
       ,a.ShipRate
       ,a.CouponDiscountCode
       ,a.CouponDiscount
       ,a.CustomerDiscount
       ,a.CustomerDiscountPercent
       ,a.SalesTaxTotal
       ,a.Payment_Method
       ,a.Credit_Card_Type
       ,a.Credit_Card_Number
       ,a.Order_Date
       ,a.BILL_TYPE
       ,a.Order_Net
       ,c.SHIP_ADDRESS1
       ,c.SHIP_ADDRESS2
       ,c.SHIP_CITY
       ,c.SHIP_STATE
       ,c.SHIP_POSTAL_CODE
       ,c.SHIP_COUNTRY
       , row_number() over (partition by a.order_no
                            order by SHIP_ADDRESS1, SHIP_ADDRESS2, SHIP_CITY, SHIP_STATE
                                   , SHIP_POSTAL_CODE, SHIP_COUNTRY) as rn
FROM Orders AS a
JOIN Customers AS b
    ON a.customer_no = b.customer_no
JOIN numberLineItems c
    ON c.order_no = a.order_no
WHERE a.AccountName = 'mywebaccount'
       AND a.billing_status <> 'Canceled'
       AND a.transferred = 0
       AND a.order_status <> 'Canceled'
) as x
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY order_date
       , order_no;
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't do `FROM sometable1 AS t1, sometable2 AS t2`. Always join explicitly. Secondly, from the way your case looks, some variant of `APPLY` would suit nicely.

Here's my version:

```
SELECT a.Order_no
      ,a.Customer_no
      ,a.BILL_LAST_NAME
      ,a.BILL_FIRST_NAME
      ,b.email
      ,a.BILL_ADDRESS1
      ,a.BILL_ADDRESS2
      ,a.BILL_CITY
      ,a.BILL_STATE
      ,a.BILL_POSTAL_CODE
      ,a.BILL_COUNTRY
      ,b.Address_Type
      ,a.BILL_PHONE
      ,a.BILL_PHONE_EXT
      ,a.Order_Date
      ,a.billing_status
      ,a.PO_Number
      ,a.Customer_comments
      ,a.ShipMethodShipperDesc
      ,a.ShipRate
      ,a.CouponDiscountCode
      ,a.CouponDiscount
      ,a.CustomerDiscount
      ,a.CustomerDiscountPercent
      ,a.SalesTaxTotal
      ,a.Payment_Method
      ,a.Credit_Card_Type
      ,a.Credit_Card_Number
      ,a.Order_Date
      ,a.BILL_TYPE
      ,a.Order_Net
      ,li.SHIP_ADDRESS1
      ,li.SHIP_ADDRESS2
      ,li.SHIP_CITY
      ,li.SHIP_STATE
      ,li.SHIP_POSTAL_CODE
      ,li.SHIP_COUNTRY
FROM Orders AS a
INNER JOIN Customers AS b
    ON a.customer_no = b.customer_no
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 c.SHIP_ADDRESS1
                ,c.SHIP_ADDRESS2
                ,c.SHIP_CITY
                ,c.SHIP_STATE
                ,c.SHIP_POSTAL_CODE
                ,c.SHIP_COUNTRY 
    FROM LineItems c
    WHERE c.ORDER_NO = a.ORDER_NO
    ORDER BY c.Id -- or whatever
) AS li
WHERE a.AccountName = 'mywebaccount'
AND a.billing_status <> 'Canceled'
AND a.transferred = 0
AND a.order_status <> 'Canceled'
-- no need for that exists since CROSS APPLY works like INNER JOIN
ORDER BY a.order_date,a.order_no
```

Comment: This looks a lot better than the original. Of course when using TOP we also need to have an order by.

Comment: @SeanLange Yeah, that's what happens when I'm more worried about getting the wonky indentation right than finishing my query. Edited.

Comment: Is `CROSS APPLY` better than using `Partition`?  I ended up using the partition method

Comment: @user1387756 I think it's about the same speed-wise. Style-wise I prefer my method because I find it more readable and `APPLY` is the right way to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple example and posted

[HERE on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f68b7/1)

The simplest way is just to join with the top 1 from a subquery

```
select cus.*, ord.*, sub.*
from Customer cus
join [Order] ord on ord.CustomerId = cus.Id
join (
  select it.OrderId, it.ItemName, it.ItemAddress
  from Items it
  where it.Id in (select MAX(id) from Items group by OrderId)
  ) as sub on sub.OrderId = ord.Id
```

If you want to see the first item instead the last you can replace MAX(id) with MIN(id)

Note the only "problem" is if there are no items for the order it ill not show.
But if you got orders without a item and still want to show it you can use a left join

Se the fiddle for a running example.

I hope you don't mind I used explicit joins =)

Comment: I don't have a reliable `Id` unfortunately.

Comment: You don't need one really, you can get any arbitray item and there are a loot of ways to get that in that subquery: cross apply, partition, hash, rownumber, etc